# Can this cabinet piece be repaired?

Tags: mold

I had damp and mold develop behind kitchen cabinets.

The mold penetrated all over a backboard and I got rid of it.  Then there is this bottom surface.  You can see it’s all gone black.    The positioning suggests it’s part of the damp damage.

Is this mold or something else?

1. Is there a way this can be repaired or should I just discard it?
2. Will I get penalized by the council for discarding it?

*It is the bottom part of the cabinet as per second pic. It’s disassembled but it will be higher and joined once assembled.*

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh3Xr.jpg[image]

Comment: What part of the cabinet are we looking at? You can [edit] your post to include another picture from a bit farther out to show us a nice overview of the cabinet. It would also help to include a reasonably close picture of the corner so we can see how it is attached - that will help determine what might be involved in executing a repair/replace.

Comment: I'm thinking that's just water/moisture (which is pretty bad for particleboard) but without knowing the time-frame involved or exactly what I'm looking at in the picture it's hard to say. Chances are it can be repaired (actually, replaced) but we need some context to understand the scope of the problem(s).

Comment: How deep is the damage?  If not too deep, scrape out the loose stuff and coat with a good wood glue.

Comment: What sort of tool would I scrape with?  I think its gone too deep just to scrape it out, to get rid of the black more drastic action maybe required but as in the pic u see what i see, only not as clear.

Comment: @GregNickoloff I have provided a pic of the placing.  Water came through the back, destroyed particleboard which you cannot see(a separate piece i have discarded, and some went down and destroyed back of bottom panel i am asking about.  thanks.

Comment: The damage you are showing on the edge, appears to be more from water seeping into the board at the edge.  The board does not appears to be deformed  The water marks are on the center portion of the edge. I do see minor damage in that area there.  If you want to do any repair, just apply a spanner board on the bottom side along the edge.

Comment: Make a new one, measure precisely and mark & cut accurately.

Comment: I'd get a sheet of good 3/4" plywood and make a new piece. Particleboard is kind of lame anyhow, and once it's been wet, it certainly doesn't get any better. You should be able to "trace" the old piece and cut out the plywood to match. Give it a coat or two of paint and you're better off that you were to begin with. I don't know about being penalized by the Council, but wouldn't you face some kind of displeasure putting it together with damaged panels anyhow?

Comment: That board is part of the back which no one sees. Just take a saw and cut the wet part of. Use some duct tape to seal the that edge, so water can't get in.